# Spring compile time weaving transaction rollback

Tags: spring, gwt, google-plugin-eclipse, compile-time-weaving

I'm trying to get `Aspectj` `Compile Time Weaving`(CTW) configured in `Spring`. However after adding `mode="aspectj"` to the `tx:annotation-driven`, the transactions all fail and no entities are stored in the database as a result.

Here is the relevant part of my configuration:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" mode="aspectj" />
<context:spring-configured />
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package='some.package' />
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
<property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id='entityManagerFactory' class='org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean'><property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPU" /> 
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

I also have a aop.xml in /META-INF (not sure the file is needed though)

```
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC
        "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
<aspectj>
    <weaver>
        <!-- only weave classes in our application-specific packages -->
        <include within="some.package.*" />
    </weaver>
    <aspects>
        <aspect
            name="org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AnnotationTransactionAspect" />
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

Some remarks:

- I am stuck to CTW (so no LTW) because of the environment I'm working
  with.
- I use `@PersistenceContext` to get the `EntityManager`
- Without mode="aspectj" in tx:annotation-driven the transactions
  run fine
- I'm not using `Spring MVC`
- I'm using GWT 2.5

## edit:

My project has a `Maven` nature, and I had to add this plugin too. But I run the application using `Eclipse` and the `Google Plugin`. I run the project as `A Web Application (google plugin)`. I'm not sure if this code in `Maven` is properly initialised...

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.3</version>
<configuration>
<complianceLevel>1.6</complianceLevel>
<encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
<aspectLibraries>
<aspectLibrary>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
</aspectLibrary>
</aspectLibraries>
</configuration>
<executions>
<execution>
<goals>
<goal>compile</goal>
<goal>test-compile</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

This are the relevant parts of my pom:

```
<properties>
    <aspectj.version>1.6.11</aspectj.version>
    <aspectj-maven-plugin.version>1.2</aspectj-maven-plugin.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
     <dependency>
           <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
           <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
           <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
           <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
           <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
           <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
     </dependency>
...
</dependencies>
...

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <!-- NB: do not use 1.3 or 1.3.x due to MASPECTJ-90 - wait for 1.4 -->
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <outxml>true</outxml>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-security-aspects</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <encoding>utf-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

It works without any problems and without any `aop.xml`

Comment: That's basicly the same. The problem is I use GWT's development mode and this aspectj-maven-plugin isn't probably compiled. When I run the project as a Webapplication using the google plugin this is probably skipped... But how can I use CTW weaving then using GWT?

Comment: @GTT4Ever: If GWT is the problem, then I can not help you, sorry.

Comment: I don't think GWT is the problem. Is there any test I can do to get further insights in this problem?

Comment: Write a small sample application wihtout GWT

Comment: I think this problem is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047071/compile-time-weaving-null-pointer-exception . I supplied a small sample application there.

Comment: @Arjan: you are the first one how noticed it. ;-) I corrected it.